# Dynamic setting input type in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, radio-button

Please can anybody explain why this code doesnt work, i try set input types dynamically, but this is not working.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form #f="ngForm">

      <input [type]="rtype" value="beef" name="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Beef
      <input [type]="rtype" value="lamb" name="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Lamb
      <input [type]="rtype" value="fish" name="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Fish
    </form>

    <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>  <!-- {food: 'lamb' } -->
    <p>myFood value: {{ myFood }}</p>  <!-- 'lamb' -->
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  myFood = 'lamb';
  rtype='radio';
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule       ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

also i try use `type={{rtype}}`, but this also doesnt work

I am read this https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property. But not understand why it is not working in Angular. May be angular not call https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor. Please explain.

Also when i create simple radio in html, and then try change the input type property from console it works fine 
for example was input.type="radio", became input.type="checkbox" in browser i see that radio changed to the normal checkbox.

My plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/rwJPe2YZ9axMns0NaMNJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I used this before

```
<input type="{{inputType}}" />
```

In your component:

```
inputType: string = "radio"
```